# How to display full background image file

Tags: html, css

I've encountered a problem that I can't display full background image.

The code is below.
I think it can work,but it doesn't work.
The image displayed only based on line count.

Please tell me how to display full sized image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- .tests {
      background: url(contents01_left_bg.png);
      background-position: center top;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tests">
    a</br>
    a
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You only need: 'background: `url(contents01_left_bg.png);` and `background-size:cover;`. `background-size` is supported everywhere and no vendor prefix is needed. You also shouldn't be using HTML comment syntax inside of a CSS stylesheet.

Comment: what are the dimensions of the background image?

Comment: @MichaelCoker That shouldn't matter because of `background-size:cover`. From MDN: *"The image "covers" the entire width or height of the container."*

Comment: @ScottMarcus well, if you have the image dimensions, you can use padding or padding on a pseudo element of the parent to recreate the aspect ratio of the image, then the div will always be the same aspect ratio of the image, showing the whole thing instead of just what will fit based on the content.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I believe that even with the aspect ratio thrown off, `background-size:cover` still forces it to scale to the size of the container. So, you may well get a skewed image, but you should still see all of it.

Comment: Right, `cover` makes the whole element covered by the background, but depending on the content, you may not (very likely won't) see all of the background image in the element unless the content in the element matches the aspect ratio of the image. Posted an answer, we'll see if that's what OP is going for.

Comment: See my updated answer for a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rethinking your question, I believe the best approach is not to use a background image. If you place the image as regular content to a container, that container will expand to the full size of the image.

Then, you can create another container for the rest of the content and float that content over the image.

The result is the full sized image with other content above it and you don't have to worry about repeating images or aspect ratios.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
  
   #parent { border:1px solid black; }
   .tests {
      float:left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/963/very_emotional_emoticons/128/128_33.png">
    <div class="tests">
      a<br>
      a
     </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>More content</p>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick and polite response!! My problem has been resolved by Mr.Michael Coker's code.But I find your code also can resolve my problem.It's better because I don't have to worry about aspect ratio.

Comment: @西本至秀 Please up vote all answers that were helpful and mark the best one as "the" answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a full background image, with the whole image visible in the element, you need to make the element match the aspect ratio of the background image. Otherwise, the element will just be as tall/wide as the content inside of it. If you have the image dimensions, you can use padding or padding on a pseudo element of the parent to recreate the aspect ratio of the image, then the div will always be the same aspect ratio of the image, showing the whole thing instead of just what will fit based on the content.

To recreate the aspect ratio, divide the height of the image by the width (800 / 1200 in my example), multiply by 100 to get a % (66.6666666666%), and apply that as `padding-bottom` of the parent or a pseudo element of the parent.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background: url('http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/monkey/monkey-04.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat / cover;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 66.6667%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  a<br>
    a
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick and polite response!! My problem has been resolved by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```